# Bow and Arrow: Move arrow with enemy gameobjects death animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, gameobject

I'm able to make my arrow stick into the enemy gameobject upon a successful hit, but as soon as the gameobject goes into it's animation state the arrow stays in place. Is there a way to incorporate the arrow gameobject into the enemy gameobject upon collision so that it moves accordingly with the enemy's death state animation?

Comment: Did you child the arrow to the thing it hit?

Comment: No it is not childed to the enemy gameobject. I am hoping to find a way to do this programmatically in C# upon collision.

Comment: @MurphyRyan BugFinder already point out the solution. Look for the collision's gameobject and attach the arrow as child of that object. The engine will do the rest.